# How to calculate the time difference between two columns?

Tags: r

I have a beginner question. I have the following data:

| started_at | ended_at | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/08/2021 17:15 | 10/08/2021 17:22 | NA |
| 10/08/2021 17:23 | 10/08/2021 17:39 | NA |
| 21/08/2021 02:34 | 21/08/2021 02:50 | NA |
| 21/08/2021 06:52 | 21/08/2021 07:08 | NA |
| 19/08/2021 11:55 | 19/08/2021 12:04 | NA |
| 19/08/2021 12:41 | 19/08/2021 12:47 | NA |

I would like to calculate the time difference and add that to the duration column.

Comment: You don't have times, you have strings. First, convert them to `POSIXt` class timestamps (`as.POSIXct`), then *just subtract*. You might need to control the units of the subtraction, as POSIX subtraction does not always return "seconds" difference; that's simple enough with `difftime(.., units="secs")` (as @TarJae's answer shows) or just `as.numeric(ended_at - started_at, units="secs")`.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `difftime`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("at"), dmy_hm), # you don't need this if your colums is already in datetime format
         duration=difftime(ended_at, started_at))
```

Output:

```
           started_at            ended_at duration
1 2021-08-10 17:15:00 2021-08-10 17:22:00   7 mins
2 2021-08-10 17:23:00 2021-08-10 17:39:00  16 mins
3 2021-08-21 02:34:00 2021-08-21 02:50:00  16 mins
4 2021-08-21 06:52:00 2021-08-21 07:08:00  16 mins
5 2021-08-19 11:55:00 2021-08-19 12:04:00   9 mins
6 2021-08-19 12:41:00 2021-08-19 12:47:00   6 mins
```

Answer (score 1):

The Brute method:

If your using a language with Date objects convert your Date/Time objects to milliseconds.

Then

```
diff = endDateMilliseconds - startDateMilliseconds
```

You might have some library to convert back to time but you can do it manually

```
durationInMinutes = diff / 60000
```

If you need days & minutes you would need to use remainder `%`.

```
days = diff / (1440 * 60000)  
mins = (diff % (1440 * 60000))/60000
```

Probably better ways to do this depending on language your using.

Comment: Also Integer objects for your result days or minutes to ignore decimals or you can apply floor (round down) method if your language supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  mutate(ended_at = dmy_hm(ended_at),
         started_at = dmy_hm(started_at)) %>% 
  mutate(duration = as.numeric(difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins")))
```

| started_at | ended_at | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-10 17:15:00 | 2021-08-10 17:22:00 | 7 |
| 2021-08-10 17:23:00 | 2021-08-10 17:39:00 | 16 |
| 2021-08-21 02:34:00 | 2021-08-21 02:50:00 | 16 |
| 2021-08-21 06:52:00 | 2021-08-21 07:08:00 | 16 |
| 2021-08-19 11:55:00 | 2021-08-19 12:04:00 | 9 |
| 2021-08-19 12:41:00 | 2021-08-19 12:47:00 | 6 |